# DetachedInstanceError: Instance <TCustomer at 0x428ddf0> is not bound to a Session

Tags: python, pyramid

I have looked at previous examples of people having similar problems however I can't seem to figure out why mine won't work since I'm using the same session.

This is my block of code that simply queries the db to see if a customer exists, then use that customer in another insert. But as soon as i hit the line `transaction.commit()` it throws the `DetachedInstanceError`. Could this be from an earlier `transaction.commit()` in another method?

```
@view_config(route_name='create_location', renderer='templates/main.html')
def create_location(request):

    #get the json data from the ajax call
    data = request.json_body

    session = DBSession

    locationName = data["location"]
    custID = data["custID"]

    Customer = session.query(TCustomer).filter(TCustomer.ixCustomer==custID).one()

    #create customer
    Location = TLocation(sDescription=locationName, ixCustomer=Customer)
    session.add(Location)
    session.flush()
    transaction.commit()

    return Response('ok')
```

this is my DBSession:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension(keep_session=True)))
```

had to add the `keep_session=True`

Then instead of doing `session = DBSession()` all I had to do was just use `DBSession` for my queries and session work

Answer (score 2):

> Could this be from an earlier transaction.commit() in another method?

**YES,** if that another method is called within the same request-response cycle - once the transaction is committed, SQLAlchemy can't make any guarantees that any in-memory ORM objects still represent the actual state of the database, so you can't just fetch an object in one transaction and save it back in another without explicitly merging the now-detached object into a new session.

**You generally should not be using `transaction.commit()` in your code at all.** The idea behind using `ZopeTransactionExtension` is that it ties SQLAlchemy transactions to Pyramid's request-response cycle - a new session is constructed when a request starts, and is committed if the request succeeds or rolled back if the request fails (i.e. an exception is raised in your view). Within your code you shouldn't be concerned with committing anything - just add your new objects to the session:

```
@view_config(route_name='create_location', renderer='templates/main.html')
def create_location(request):

    #get the json data from the ajax call
    data = request.json_body

    customer = DBSession.query(Customer).filter(Customer.id==data["custID"]).one()
    session.add(Location(description=data["location"], customer=customer))

    return Response('ok')
```

*(couldn't resist making the code a little bit more resembling "normal" Python code... Hungarian notation is... err... not very commonly used these days... Thanks for giving me a nostalgic flashback :))) See [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for details).*

In *rare* cases you may want to some part of your request to succeed no matter what, or even to save data to the database only if an error happens (logging errors to the database may be an example). In those cases you use a separate session which is configured without ZopeTransactionExtension. You need to commit such session manually:

```
try:
    do_something_which_might_fail()
except Exception as e:
    session = ErrorLogSession()
    session.add(SomeORMObject(message=format_exception(e))
    session.commit()
```

Further reading:

- [When do I construct a Session, when do I commit it, and when do I close it?](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#session-faq-whentocreate) -a hight-level overview in SQLAlchemy docs. "TL;DR: As a general rule, keep the lifecycle of the session separate and external from functions and objects that access and/or manipulate database data." Note that Pyramid already does all the session management for you - separately end externally from your code.
- [Databases Using SQLAlchemy](http://pyramid-tutorials.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started/11-sqlalchemy/#application-steps) - a basic Pyramid application which uses SQLAlchemy. See `dev wikipage_add()` function for an example of typical code which saves some data to the database.

Comment: thank you for this master piece of information. I have figured out the problem but this has given me some good insight. As for the coding style, I'm new to python so hence probably why the coding style doesn't resemble typical python code lol